# Magento 2 File Upload Issue with Multiple Fields in Admin side

Tags: magento-2.1, file-upload

I have two fields in admin side form. Logo and brand_product_image. I am using following code to upload file and save in database.

```
$fields = array('logo','brand_product_image');

                foreach($fields as $field):
                     $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', ['fileId' => $field]
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('brand'));
                if ($result['error'] == 0) {
                    $data[$field] = 'brand' . $result['file'];
                }
                endforeach;
```

When i am saving data m not getting value of `brand_product_image`. But i if remove logo from `$fields` array i am getting value of it.

Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this create uploader instance before foreach not inside loop

```
 $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', ['fileId' => $field]);

    foreach($fields as $field):
         //rest of code
    endforeach;
```

Comment: i need upload the multiple image in single upload